# How to make a packaged firefox os privileged

Tags: permissions, manifest, firefox-os

I've been developing a Firefox os application, I faced some problems but I've managed to make a good application, everything is working fine.

I wanted to use some firefox os privileged Api, so I want to turn intro privileged apps, I just added the type in manifest file.

after testing the app, the application doesn't work when I added the privileged type in the manifest file knowing that I make JSON requests to get json files and I store data as indexeddb.

Comment: Could you post your full manifest here? Which API are you trying to use exactly? What are the logs saying? We need more information really :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with firefox os CSP.

I changed some of my code to avoid default CSP restrictions. You should check :

[Firefox OS Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Building_apps_for_Firefox_OS/CSP)